# Table pagination - li's aren't appending correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
function pagination() {     
 $('.paginated').each(function() {
    var currentPage = 0;
    var numPerPage = $("#instancesPerPage").val();
    var $table = $(this);
    $table.bind('repaginate', function() {
        $table.find('tbody tr').hide().slice(currentPage * numPerPage, (currentPage + 1) * numPerPage).show();
    });
    $table.trigger('repaginate');
    var numRows = $table.find('tbody tr').length;
    var numPages = Math.ceil(numRows / numPerPage);
    var $pager = $('<ul></ul>');

    for (var page = 0; page < numPages; page++) {
    var pageUrl = '<a href="#">' + page + '</a>';
        $('<li></li>').html(pageUrl).on('click', {
            newPage: page
        }, function(event) {
            currentPage = event.data['newPage'];
            $table.trigger('repaginate');
            $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        }).appendTo($pager);    
    }
    $pager.appendTo('#pager');
    $("ul li:first-child").addClass('active');
 });
};
```

If my table has 8 rows and my numPerPage.value is 2 the above function will produce the following:

```
<div class="pagination-instances pagination-small pagination-right" id="pager">
    <ul></ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">0</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Upon calling the following function when selecting another numPerPage.value:

```
 $('#instancesPerPage').on("change", function() {
  pagination();
 });
```

My table page changes to the correct numPerPage.value but the li's are not updated correctly and becoming a mess.

```
<div class="pagination-instances pagination-small pagination-right" id="pager">
    <ul></ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">0</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">0</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">0</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Apparently this has something todo with the appendTo I am using, but I have no idea how to correct that. Also I have no idea why there is a empty `<ul></ul>`.

Comment: @akonsu sure, we are not at Ikea so I don't expect a prefab answer, could you point me in the right direction tho?

Comment: I would check the value of $pager variable after the loop exits, and the contents of the #pager element. If you are on chrome then you can use console.log API to display things in the browser's console.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the problem. Your code (though somewhat odd) seems to work fine http://jsfiddle.net/gZmWh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling pagination() multiple times won't work, because you're not unbinding the event and you are appending to `<div id="pager">` rather than replacing the content.

Also, if you have multiple paginated tables, they all try add a `ul` to the same `<div id="pager">`. By specifying a target div for the pager in the table, you can have multiple paginated tables with multiple pagers.

```
<select id="instancesPerPage">
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="999999999">All</option>
</select> Instances per page

<table data-provide="pagination" data-pager="#pager">
    <tr><td>Row 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 8</td></tr>
</table>

<div class="pagination pagination-small" id="pager"></div>

<table data-provide="pagination" data-pager="#pager2">
    <tr><td>ABC 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>ABC 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>ABC 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>ABC 4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>ABC 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>ABC 6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>ABC 7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>ABC 8</td></tr>
</table>

<div class="pagination pagination-small" id="pager2"></div>
​
```

Using js

```
function pagination() {
 $('table[data-provide=pagination]').each(function() {
    var $table = $(this);
    var $pager = $('<ul></ul>');

    var currentPage = 0;
    var numPerPage = $("#instancesPerPage").val();
    var numRows = $table.find('tbody tr').length;
    var numPages = Math.ceil(numRows / numPerPage);

    $table.unbind('repaginate');

    $table.bind('repaginate', function() {
        $table.find('tbody tr').hide().slice(currentPage * numPerPage, (currentPage + 1) * numPerPage).show();
    });

    for (var page = 0; page < numPages; page++) {
        var link = '<a href="#">' + page + '</a>';

        $('<li></li>').html(link).on('click', { newPage: page}, function(event) {
            currentPage = event.data['newPage'];
            $table.trigger('repaginate');
            $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        }).appendTo($pager);    
    }

    $pager.find("li:first-child").addClass('active');

    $($table.data('pager')).html($pager);
    $table.trigger('repaginate');
 });
};

pagination();

$('#instancesPerPage').on("change", function() {
 pagination();
});
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gZmWh/10/

Comment: I only have one table on that page. But I guess it is adding to the same div when triggered to repaginate if the numPerPage has changed. In the above comment you mention 'somewhat odd code'. What would you change then?

Comment: Most things I'd change are here in the answer. Most important don't use (global) id's for elements while looping through each table. Also I don't see why you'd have an input with the page size, rather make it a data attribute.

Comment: The input for the page size is to select the items per page, like this:

`<select id="instancesPerPage">
           <option value="10">10</option>
           <option value="25">25</option>
           <option value="50">50</option>
           <option value="100">100</option>
           <option value="999999999">All</option>
         </select> Instances per page`

Comment: I have changed your code to what I am having http://jsfiddle.net/gZmWh/8/ and it is giving me the same results (problems).

Comment: You should have put that in your question in the first place. But I'll have a look.

Comment: That is the main subject of my question? "My table page changes to the correct numPerPage.value but the li's are not updated correctly and becoming a mess." :) I am sorry for the trouble!

Comment: I see, no problem. Next time just include a jsFiddle, so there's no confusion. Have a look at the corrected answer. It should do the trick.